# Why use double casting in this example from ARM CMSIS?

Tags: c, casting, armcc

So I have `(((uint32_t)(int32_t)IRQn) >> 5UL)`, where IRQn is an enum with range from -14 to 81.

From what I can see, it's first cast to int32_t, and then to uint32_t. Afterwards, it's shifted to left. Finally, it's used (outside of given code example) as an array index.

As a test, I wrote the following code and compiled it with the same compiler:

```
int a=0, b=0, c=0, d=0;

a=-5;
b=(int32_t)a;
c=(uint32_t)b;
d=(uint32_t)a;
```

From what I can see, all 4 numbers have the same binary value at the end. This leads me to belive that `((uint32_t)IRQn)` would have worked as a cast as well.

So is there any other reason why we'd need to do the cast two times?

Comment: @tilz0R Quite interesting that I didn't get that when searching. Thanks!

Comment: It is exactly the same as `(uint32_t)IRQn`, if IRQn is indeed in that range you mentioned